# Is there serious research on superluminal travel?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light

I was wondering if there are any serious attempts, or any ideas for loopholes in the current theories, that would enable us humans to travel with a speed greater than the speed of light?

Comment: The short answer is "I have not seen any.". The longer answer is that the universe is almost completely transparent to photons, so if one wanted to travel long distances, it would be as a beam of light. How to go from a biological body to a beam of light and back, that, of course, is not a physics problem.

Answer (score 2):

In special relativity particles that move faster than the speed of light are commonly called [Tachyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) and there is some research about the properties of such particles. Nevertheless, most physicists regards them as unphysical, because their proper time is imaginary.

Comment: Could you please expand on that a bit? When the OP inquired about serious research, he probably meant something like a critical review or thereabouts. The wiki article on tachyons shows up as a second result in a Google search for "superluminal particles". He/she probably wanted a little more than that.